# How do I change the colour of context menu in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, colors

I'd like to change the colour of the background of context menu in Windows 10.
My current colour is gray:

[image]

I have seen over the Internet that this colour could be white, as in this photo:

[image]

How do I change the colour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think second photo is from build 10240 where context menus **were** *white* by default, in the last builds they changed color to gray and there is nothing you can do about it... Except two things:

- **use high-contrast theme**.
- **use 3-rd party program[Moo0 Transparent Menu] to change color of menu**.

Comment: In my opinion, [**Moo0 Transparent Menu**](https://www.moo0.com/software/TransparentMenu/) not a good choice. // **1**. It makes the menu look bad for some programs; for example, compare `Mocha Coffee` skin results for [**Tablacus Explorer**](https://i.imgur.com/tb5s907.png) and [**Firefox**](https://i.imgur.com/yAngrFg.png). // **2**. Solely pre-installed skins supported; I can't make own skin, where all colors are good visible.

Comment: // **3**. It not open source. It is unclear how this program works. // **4**. Possible undesirable behavior — see [**VirusTotal scanning result**](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/8c54cbd8b803a2c6e20143484f8a61259f976efadfe2bc8e468a82d9f3567d1e/detection). // Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных I wish there was an open-source alternative, but sadly I haven't found any. And for "Firefox" problem you can use the `userChrome.css` to change the context menu inside Firefox as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can change that to gray, but you can try enabling classic context menu using these steps, which changes the highlight/bg color to blue.

Start Regedit.exe and go to:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\FlightedFeatures

Create a DWORD value named `ImmersiveContextMenu`

Leave its value data as 0

And a fresh login, Context menu looks like this:

[image]

Whereas it appeared like this, before applying the registry edit.

[image]

Src: [MS Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/right-click-menu-messed-up-after-10586-update/b834d86f-0e15-4b5d-8383-119a073cd84c)

Comment: he wants the opposite, from legacy gray to this new color